# Remove the GotFocus event handler from the Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to remove the GotFocus event handler from the WebBrowser control in .Net4 so that it won't be fired? I need to remove it because the DevExpress ASPxHtmlEditor requires a triple click to put a cursor in the spot where you want it to go. Our users are not always quick or steady with the mouse so tripple clicking is not a good fix. We arehoping that removing the GotFocus event will fix the problem.

Their explanation of the issue:
" have investigated this issue and concluded that it is caused by the WebBrowser control behavior when the control is placed in an Mdi container.
Every time you click within a web page (including the HtmlEditor's edit area), the WebBrowser's GotFocus event occurs. As a result, the HtmlEditor's edit area loses focus. By design, if the HtmlEditor's edit area has no focus, the cursor is placed to its old position within the edit area when you click within it (to see this in action, you can open the HtmlEditor's demo page, click within the HtmlEditor's edit area, then click outside it, and click within the edit area again).

If the parent form is not an Mdi container, the WebBrowser's GotFocus event does not occur, the edit area does not lose focus, and the cursor position is changed when you click within the edit area.

I am afraid we cannot fix issues in controls that belong to third-party companies."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the RemoveHandler statement as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac.aspx).  Can't say what the effects of that might be on the rest of your application, though.